# Powershell Parameter, Validate it according to Regex and Pass a Boolean value

Tags: regex, validation, powershell, parameters

Here is the scenario - I am writing a script. I need a yes to pass a Yes/No or Y/N response to a question. I need it validated (so anything other than a yes or a y response will throw an error) and then ideally I'd like the value converted to a Boolean $true for a Yes/Y response or $false for a No/N response

Here is what I've got so far - and suffice to say, It's not working. I'm a little new to adding Parameters and adding validation for them - so I'd appreciate a little assistance and guidance.

```
[parameter(mandatory=$true,
HelpMessage = "Is this Server Managed Server? Y/N?"
)]
[Validatescript({
if ($_ -match '^y(es)?$'){
    $true
    }

 else { ($_ -match '^n(o)?$')
    $False
    }

[string]$Managed = "Managed Server Y/N"
}
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that what you are looking for is 'ValidateSet' so that your script only accepts predetermined values for certain parameters, defined by you. Here is an example of 'ValidateSet' being used in a function:

```
Function Test-Validation{
    param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,HelpMessage="Is this Server Managed Server? Y/N?")]
    [ValidateSet("Yes","y","No","n")]
    $var1
    )
    IF($var1 -match '[Yes|Y]'){
        return $true
    } Else {
        Return $false
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you kindly - that is just what I was after - although I made a slight change - instead of returning the boolean value - I assigned it to another variable (which will be called later in the script when I need it)

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad that helped!

Answer (score 0):

you are thinking it wrong, `validatescript` should return `$true` in order for it to work, you are better of implementing this as part of your actual code or just implement a switch:

```
[switch]$Managed
```

edit: so validatescript will throw an error if it doesnt return `$true` you can't use it to assign true or false (or anything else) to the parameter, it only validates the parameter.